# Code Length in IDE ( w/o modeling support ) versus Code Efficiecy in Compilation in Delphi

Tags: performance, delphi, events, coding-style

So - highly hypothetical question and more like discussion about your coding style and practice you use daily.

I will take as example: CodeGear RAD Studio 2009 (sorry to all D7 fans, but Unicode rules).

I have capability to expand/collapse functions/procedures/records and few other complex data structures, but what if code is lengthy?

What makes the task and its accomplishment efficient - the time required to add comments (its req actually) and expand/collapse necessary area or use OMT offered possibilities?

To give example input from myself - I have small app, about 1,5k lines and I do not use Modeling. Is it smart enough or do I lose a lot of time if I need to find some simple references or (event) calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is a bout finding your way into code (yours or someone elses').

I use [Model Maker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) for browsing through source code (and for refactoring existing code, and creating new code). At [EUR 99](http://www.modelmakertools.com/order/newlicenses.html), it is dead cheap for what it does.

It usually gives me a perfect overview of what I need, and has a nice 'search' interface as well.
If I need more complex searches, I usually use the [GExperts](http://gexperts.org/) [(grep) search](http://www.gexperts.org/Readme.txt) function: it is blazingly fast, and with good naming of your identifiers, it is usually a breeze to find stuff.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you very much for your info, mate! The prob is that I have not official emplojee for now, so 99 euro is reasonable money ... :)
But - I will check your links for sure!

Comment: I second on Model Maker and GExpert. Although I still use the command line grep.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know what is more efficient:

1. Use comments and expandable sections.
2. Use moddeling techniques.

I think it depends on personal style. Modeling can be great, but has dangers of spending too much time creating nice pictures.

We have a large app 500k+ lines. We do not use collapsable sections because we keep our file size acceptable and we have a good file organisation structure. We sometimes use modeling if complex parts are added (class diagrams and state diagrams). And we use lots of comment to explain difficult parts.

Comment: Yes, u got the idea. Ok, thanks for your info ;)
Anbody else, please?!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Delphi 2009 you can use also the *Delphi Class Explorer* (in the *View* menu) in order to see your classes. It seems a little bit cryptic but only for the first 5 minutes. After this you will get used with it.

Also you can use [CnPack](http://cnpack.org) a very impressive package in order to help you manage your project. Basically, in the IDE appears a new menu called 'CnPack' which has a bunch of wizards to help you find the way out in the source. Some examples:

- Uses Cleaner
- Procedure List (it gives you the incremental search capability for your procedures - very neat)
- Bookmark Browser

etc.